# Wildcard route with ui-router-ng2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, auth0

I'm attempting to use ui-router-ng2 with Auth0, an authentication-as-a-service provider. The problem is that after login Auth0 redirects the user to a url that looks like this:

http://localhost:3000/#access_token=alCUyTW2WKLkV8Fq&{etc...}

I've tried changing that redirect url so it hits a component but that doesn't seem possible with auth0.

With ui-router 1, it was possible to add an http intercept to handle this but there's no http intercept function in angular 2 at this point.

When using auth0 with angular 2 default router, the redirect is handled like this:

```
  this
    .router
    .events
    .filter(event => event.constructor.name === 'NavigationStart')
    .filter(event => (/access_token|id_token|error/).test(event.url))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.lock.resumeAuth(window.location.hash, (error, authResult) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
```

I've gone through the ui-router-ng2 docs and don't see a way to do something similar.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following in my app's root component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    console.log("App root component created");

    // Auth0 doesn't redirect properly to /#/ URLs so we have to capture token here 
    var regex = /(id_token=)([^&]*)/;
    var vals = regex.exec(window.location.hash);
    if (vals != null) {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', vals[2]);
      if(localStorage.getItem('preAuthURL') != null) { window.location.href = localStorage.getItem('preAuthURL');}
    }

  }
}
```